# Assigning array or table variable in Oracle

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle12c

I am trying to update a stored procedure in an Oracle package. Originally, SP was set to assume a single item id would be passed to it but now there is possibility of set of item ids to be passed in the form of comma separated string.

I am trying to split this string into a set of strings and loop through it. I managed to split the string but can't seem to be able to assign it to a variable that I can use to loop through.

```
PROCEDURE USPGETSOMTHING
(
IPSITEMIDS                VARCHAR2,
....,
CUR_OUT                   OUT GETDATACURSOR
)
IS
...;
V_NEWITEM VARCHAR2(4000);
V_NEWITEMLIST VARCHAR2(4000);  

-- Tried declaring an array; not good!
type array_t is table of varchar(20);
V_NEWITEMLIST array_t;

BEGIN

-- string passed to SP is in the form of "'LP060500105','EM060500103'"
V_NEWITEM := REPLACE(IPSITEMIDS, '''', '');

-- This comma-separated string will actually be V_NEWITEM
SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR('LP060500105,EM060500103', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) INTO V_NEWITEMLIST FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY instr('LP060500105,EM060500103', ',',1, LEVEL-1) > 0;
```

The above does not work, I get:

```
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

Next issue I need to tackle is returning the result in a data table.

Currently, I use:

```
IF (...)
....
LVSQUERY:='SELECT '''|| V_NEWITEM ||''' AS ITEMID, '''|| V_OUTCOME ||''' AS OUTCOME FROM DUAL';
END IF;

OPEN CUR_OUT FOR LVSQUERY;
```

How would I make sure that resulting data table will have as many rows as number of item IDs, the result of splitting the item id string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a CURSOR and loop through the records.

```
PROCEDURE USPGETSOMTHING
(
IPSITEMIDS                VARCHAR2,
....,
CUR_OUT                   OUT GETDATACURSOR
)
IS
...;
V_NEWITEM VARCHAR2(4000);
V_NEWITEMLIST VARCHAR2(4000);  

CURSOR cur IS
SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR('LP060500105,EM060500103', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) V_NEWITEMLIST 
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY instr('LP060500105,EM060500103', ',',1, LEVEL-1) > 0;

-- Tried declaring an array; not good!
type array_t is table of varchar(20);
V_NEWITEMLIST array_t;

BEGIN

-- string passed to SP is in the form of "'LP060500105','EM060500103'"
V_NEWITEM := REPLACE(IPSITEMIDS, '''', '');

FOR rec IN cur LOOP
    --- whatever you want to do referencing the field in the cursor by rec.V_NEWITEMLIST
END LOOP;
```

You can also try the OPEN ... FOR

```
PROCEDURE uspgetsomthing
(    IPSITEMIDS                VARCHAR2,

CUR_OUT                   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS


BEGIN

OPEN CUR_OUT    FOR

   SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR('LP060500105,EM060500103', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) V_NEWITEMLIST 
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY instr('LP060500105,EM060500103', ',',1, LEVEL-1) > 0;
END; -- Procedure
```

Comment: At "FOR EACH ..." it throws the error: "Error(186,12): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "REC" when expecting one of the following:     in "

Comment: Sorry... my VB.Net coming out... it's just a FOR

Comment: Thanks. I tried to set V_NEWITEM = rec.V_NEWITEMLIST inside the loop but get the error "V_NEWITEMLIST must be declared first". I have the statements in same order as you listed.

Comment: Did you use a colon with the =?   V_NEWITEM := rec.V_NEWITEMLIST;

Comment: Yes, I did, typo issue!. When I run in debug an put a breakpoint and inspect "rec", I only see "Value". When I modify the inspected element from "rec" to "rec.V_NEWITELIST" it shows error. Also, would you kindly check the second part of the question, regarding storing data for each ItemID in cursor and return a data table with one row per item id? Currently it only returns one row.

Comment: OK, I figured out the error, it is OK now. I can loop through cursor. I just need to figure out how to return a data table that contains one row per item id rather than just one row it is currently returning.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `BULK COLLECT INTO` rather than just `INTO`:

```sql
SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR('LP060500105,EM060500103', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
BULK COLLECT INTO V_NEWITEMLIST
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY instr('LP060500105,EM060500103', ',',1, LEVEL-1) > 0;
```

However, a pure PL/SQL implementation that does not need a context switch to SQL and does not use (slow) regular expressions is:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/
```

*(You can replace `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST` with a user-defined collection if you prefer.)*

and then you can call that as:

```sql
V_NEWITEMLIST := split_string( 'LP060500105,EM060500103' ); -- or V_NEWITEM
```

Comment: When I used BULK COLLECT, I got "cannot mix between single row and multi-row (BULK) in INTO list". I haven't tried the second option yet.

Comment: What are you doing to generate that error? [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=83136325c1716b6d5b230b252700a493) does not throw any exceptions.